# Leaftlet - Marker listener

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I don't really understand why I can't add listener to a marker separately rather than add it when I create the marker. Take a look at the code so you could have a clearer idea.

This is my full script:

```
<script>

    map = L.map('map');

    var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osmAttrib = 'http://openstreetmap.org';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, { minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 12, attribution: osmAttrib });

    map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.3, 0.7), 9);
    map.addLayer(osm);

    map.panTo(new L.LatLng(21.0285, 105.8542));

    var marker;

    function onMapClick(e) {
        marker = L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(map).on('click', onMarkerClick);
        var divAnimation = $("div.infoTab");
        divAnimation.animate({ top: '100%' }, "slow");
    }

    map.on('click', onMapClick);

    function onMapDrag(e) {

    }

    function onMarkerClick(e) {
        //marker.bindPopup("I have just clicked this marker.").openPopup();
        var divAnimation = $("div.infoTab");
        divAnimation.animate({top: '30%'}, "slow");
    }

    //marker.on('click', onMarkerClick);
</script>
```

The script above is working, but when I created it for the first time, it's not working:

```
function onMarkerClick(e) {
        //marker.bindPopup("I have just clicked this marker.").openPopup();
        var divAnimation = $("div.infoTab");
        divAnimation.animate({top: '30%'}, "slow");
    }

    marker.on('click', onMarkerClick);
```

Can someone explain why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your `marker` is assigned when `map` is clicked. So when you register the click event on `marker`, `marker` is `undefined`.